# Regressor selection using full subset selection and simulation error minimization

Tags: regression, model-selection

I hope my question is in line with the topic of this site.

I would like to identify the set of correct regressors form the following equation, which is a kind of Henon map:

$  y(k) = 1 - a \big( y(k-2) - e(k-2) \big)^2 + b \big( y(k-4) - e(k-4) \big) $

where $ e(k) $ is the uniform random noise.

I simulated the model above by setting $ a = 1.4 $ and $ b = 0.3 $ and initial conditions $ y(1) = 0 $, $ y(2) = 1 $, $ y(3) = 0.5 $, and $ y(4) = -0.5 $, and the noise in the range $ [-0.01, 0.01] $, to have a set 1000 samples for the regressor selection.

I created a set of lagged $y(k-d), d = 1, \ldots, 5$ and then formed the possible regressor set of monomials with the maximum degree 2 from the lagged $y(k)$, i.e., to have the following regressor set:

$y(k-1)$

$\vdots$

$y(k-5)$

$y^2(k-1)$

$y(k-1)y(k-2)$

$\vdots$

$y(k-4)y(k-5)$

$y^2(k-5)$

Constant 1

All possible models are the combinations of 3 regressors above, i.e., I have 21 regressors and 1330 possible models.

I divided the data set into identification data (650 samples) and validation data (the rest). The parameters of the possible models are computed by linear regression using the identification data. The validation data are used to compute the mean-squared error (MSE) of the simulation prediction. The model with the smallest MSE is selected. Since $e(k)$ zero mean noise, I expect that the selected model would have $y^2(k-2)$, $y(k-4)$, and $Constant$.

I repeated the experiment for 100 data sets from different noise realizations. I was surprised that the experiment selects no model that has all correct regressors. Even, each experiment resulted in a different model.

Question:

- Is it expected to obtain different models for different experiment?
- Could someone here point me to a references that explain the behavior?

FYI: My background in statistics was only from my bachelor education in electrical engineering.